# Managed to leak puts function address in libc, but unable to get addresses of other functions

Tags: linux, stack-overflow, libc, exploit

I am currently learning about binary exploitation. Now i am working with a binary (Linux) that is vulnerable to a stack buffer overflow (ASLR and NX are enabled, and binary is interacted with through network), and i have developed a 2 stage exploit, the first stage leaks the address of the `puts` function in libc (from the GOT and leak by calling `puts` to send address), and the 2nd stage uses the leaked address to calculate the address of a few ROP gadgets and the `execve` function, which is used to gain Remote Code Execution.

The problem is:

I debug the binary in IDA and find the address of `puts` and `execve` so then i can calculate the offset of `execve` from `puts`. Lets say this offset is `x`. Then when using the exploit, stage 1 leaks address of `puts` and then address of `execve` is found by `puts + x`. This exploit works fine on my installation of Linux, but i have noticed that in other flavours of linux, the offset `x` of puts -> execve in libc is different (Assuming because its a different build of libc). So my question is, how can one find the address of another function using a leaked libc address, for a different Linux flavour which has an unknown offset.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because binary exploitation is not on topic for SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This exploit works fine on my installation of Linux, but i have noticed that in other flavours of linux, the offset x of puts -> execve in libc is different (Assuming because its a different build of libc).

Correct: the address will change depending on exact GLIBC source, exact version of compiler and linker used, compilation flags, etc.

In short, you can know this offset for a *specific* version of `libc6` package in a specific Linux distribution, but there are probably a 100 different variants in common use on any given day.

> So my question is, how can one find the address of another function using a leaked libc address, for a different Linux flavour which has an unknown offset.

You can't.

The only things you could do are

- download common versions of GLIBC for common distributions, compute the offset on each one, and try them all one by one, or
- guess that the offset isn't very different between the systems (you can confirm whether this is in fact true by doing above step), and just try all values between `[x - N, x + N]` (where `N` is the guessed maximum of the possible deviations).

Comment: I have found a solution, by comparing the known offsets, to a variety of different libc versions.

Comment: @JojoTheCodeDude Isn't that what I suggested above?